# Remove '.' from Thousands of Column Heads [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My DataFrame has around 9K columns, and I want to remove the `.` from every column name, see example column names below:

```
`traffic.seas1`
`traffic.seas2`
`traffic.seas3`
```

These are just three, I have 9K columns, some do not have `.` but many do. How can I remove them efficiently, as the `rename` function is too manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension on `df.columns` like this:

```
df.columns = [c.replace('.', '') for c in df.columns]
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1], 'bar.z': [2]})
>>> df.columns
Index(['bar.z', 'foo'], dtype='object')

df.columns = [c.replace('.', '') for c in df.columns]
>>> df
    barz    foo
0   2   1
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice. UVed.

Comment: I never seen before `UVed`, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.','')
```

Or `list comprehension` with `replace`:

```
df.columns = [x.replace('.','') for x in df.columns]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'traffic.seas1':list('abcdef'),
                   'traffic.seas2':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'traffic.seas3':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   D  E  F traffic.seas1  traffic.seas2  traffic.seas3
0  1  5  a             a              4              7
1  3  3  a             b              5              8
2  5  6  a             c              4              9
3  7  9  b             d              5              4
4  1  2  b             e              5              2
5  0  4  b             f              4              3

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.','')
print (df)
   D  E  F trafficseas1  trafficseas2  trafficseas3
0  1  5  a            a             4             7
1  3  3  a            b             5             8
2  5  6  a            c             4             9
3  7  9  b            d             5             4
4  1  2  b            e             5             2
5  0  4  b            f             4             3
```

**Timings**:

```
N = 9000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3, N))).add_prefix('traffic.seas')
print (df)

In [161]: %timeit df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.','')
4.4 ms ± 267 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [162]: %timeit df.columns = [x.replace('.','') for x in df.columns]
2.53 ms ± 177 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Oops, I see you added list comprehension too.